# bs4 returning browsehappy no matter the user agent

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Goal: get the list of price cards from the url: https://www.fido.ca/nac/choose-plan?type=byod
Issue: requests returning

> You are using an **outdated** browser. Please [upgrade your browser](http://browsehappy.com/) to improve your experience.

Tried: Changing user agents to [something common](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/chrome/) without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via Ajax POST request. The main page at the URL you posted doesn't contain anything.

To get all price plans, you can do POST request to different URL (you can see this url in Network Inspector in Firefox/Chrome):

```
import json
import requests

data = requests.post('https://www.fido.ca/bfa-api/v1/getAllFidoPricePlans').json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "plansMap": {
        "EDGE40TAB": {
            "rank": "9500",
            "term": "24",
            "minimumMSF": "115",
            "minimumData": {
                "EN": "GB",
                "FR": "Go",
                "data": "10"
            },
            "pricePlanCategory": "EDGE40TAB",
            "plansByData": [
                {
                    "en": "GB",
                    "fr": "Go",
                    "data": "10",
                    "plans": [
                        {
                            "planName": {
                                "en": "Infinite +10 - Edge 40",
                                "fr": "Infini +10 - Option express 40"
                            },
                            "planSku": "sku1310604",

... and so on.
```

Comment: How were you able to find the json post among all the network data coming out of chrome? Did you find anything on the actual site that allowed you to filter for that data, or did you just take a chance and use a keyword like "get"?

Comment: @dirtyw0lf I use firefox - I've just filtered all `XHR` requests...this was the biggest among them.